# multiprocessing: variable being referenced before assignment in some cases but not others

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I found the following example on this website somewhere:

```
import multiprocessing
import ctypes
import numpy as np

shared_array_base = multiprocessing.Array(ctypes.c_double, 10*10)
shared_array = np.ctypeslib.as_array(shared_array_base.get_obj())
shared_array = shared_array.reshape(10, 10)

# No copy was made
assert shared_array.base.base is shared_array_base.get_obj()

# Parallel processing
def my_func(i, def_param=shared_array):
    shared_array[i,:] = i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    pool.map(my_func, range(10))

    print shared_array
```

The above code works fine, but if I want to add an array to the shared array, something like shared_array += some_other_array (instead of the above shared_array[i,;] = i) I get

local variable 'shared_array' referenced before assignment

Any ideas why I cannot do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a variable is assigned to anywhere in a function, it is treated as a local variable.  `shared_array += some_other_array` is equivalent to `shared_array = shared_array + some_other_array`.  Thus `shared_array` is treated as a local variable, which does not exist at the time you try to use it on the right-hand side of the assignment.

If you want to use the global `shared_array` variable, you need to explicitly mark it as global by putting a `global shared_array` in your function.

The reason you don't see the error with `shared_array[i,:] = i` is that this does not assign to the variable `shared_array`.  Rather, it mutates that object, assigning to a slice of it.  In Python, assigning to a bare name (e.g., `shared_array = ...`) is very different from any other kind of assignment (e.g., `shared_array[...] = ...`), even though they look similar.

Note, incidentally, that the error has nothing to do with multiprocessing.

Comment: After doing the above I had another problem, if anyone who read this can help... thanks!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475909/multiprocessing-array-summing-issue