# multiprocessing.Array summing issue

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I have this program that basically sums arrays. I used multiprocessing because the program has to analyze 700,000 or so lines. Below I made a small script that illustrates the issue I am having

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import ctypes

t = range(100000)

list_1 = np.zeros((10))

for i in t:
    list_1 += np.array([1]*10)

list_t = mp.Array(ctypes.c_double, 10)
list_2 = np.ctypeslib.as_array(list_t.get_obj())
list_2 = list_2.reshape(10)

# No copy was made
assert list_2.base.base is list_t.get_obj()


def proc(x):
    global list_2
    list_2 += np.array([1]*10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(processes = 6)
    pool.map(proc,t)
```

The output of which:

```
In [2]: list_1
Out[2]: 
array([ 100000.,  100000.,  100000.,  100000.,  100000.,  100000.,
        100000.,  100000.,  100000.,  100000.])

In [3]: list_2
Out[3]: 
array([ 55828.,  65441.,  99300.,  68068.,  78774.,  78514.,  82393.,
        83446.,  82854.,  86987.])
```

Clearly I wanted both arrays to be like list_1. What is going on here?