# python yield generator variable scope

Tags: python, regex, scope, generator, yield

I am using yield to create a generator that returns chunks of a string that are being extracted using a regex and re.sub(). While I found an approach that worked, I am a bit confused about why it works one way but not another, as shown below:

This doesn't work (processchunk() is not assigning to the chunk declared in splitmsg):

```
def splitmsg(msg):
    chunk = None
    def processchunk(match):
        chunk = match.group(1)
        return ""
    while True:
        chunk = None
        msg = re.sub(reCHUNK,processchunk,msg,1)
        if chunk:
            yield chunk
        else:
            break
```

This does work (note the only difference being chunk is now a list chunks):

```
def splitmsg(msg):
    chunks = [ None, ]
    def processchunk(match):
        chunks[0] = match.group(1)
        return ""
    while True:
        chunks[0] = None
        msg = re.sub(reCHUNK,processchunk,msg,1)
        if chunks[0]:
            yield chunks[0]
        else:
            break
```

My question is basically why does it appear that the scoping of the chunk/chunks variable seem to depend on whether it is a plain variable or a list?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python variable scope question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/python-variable-scope-question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In python, variables can be 'pulled' from the surrounding scope if read from. So the following will work:

```
def foo():
    spam = 'eggs'
    def bar():
        print spam
foo()
```

because the variable 'spam' is being looked up in the surrounding scope, the `foo` function.

However, you cannot *change* the value of a surrounding scope. You can change *global* variables (if you declare them as `global` in your function), but you cannot do that for the variable `spam` in the above function.

(Python 3 changes this, it adds a new keyword `nonlocal`. If you define `spam` as `nonlocal` inside of `bar` you can assign to that variable a new value inside of `bar`.)

Now to your list. What happens there is that you are not altering the variable `chunks` at all. Throughout your code, `chunks` points to one list, and only to that list. As far as python is concerned, `chunks` the variable is not altered within the `processchunk` function.

What *does* happen is that you alter the *contents* of the list. You can freely assign a new value to `chunks[0]`, because that's not the variable `chunks`, it is the list referred to by `chunks`, first index. Python allows this because it is not a variable assignment, but a list manipulation instead.

So, your 'workaround' is correct, if somewhat obscure. If you use Python 3, you can declare `chunks` as `nonlocal` within `processchunk` and then things will work without lists too.

Comment: @aaa90210:  `chunk = match.group(1)` *shadows* the nonlocal variable `chunk`.

Comment: @aaa90210: `chunk[0] = match.group(1)` is syntactic sugar for `chunk.__setitem__(0, match.group(1))`.  It's not really an assignment even though it looks like it.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you are creating a new local variable called `chunk`.  A variable is treated as local to a function if you assign to it inside the function.  In the second case, you are modifying the list referred to by the outer variable `chunk`.  Because you don't assign to this variable, it's not treated as local.  See for instance [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442477/multiprocessing-variable-being-referenced-before-assignment-in-some-cases-but-n).

Assigning to a bare name in Python (`someName = ...`) is not the same as anything else; in particular it is not the same as item assignment (`someName[0] = ...`).  The latter is calling methods under the hood to mutate the list.